# An inequality about functions satisfying some properties.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, functions

For any $M_1,M_2,M_3>0$, let
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
M_1   & |x|\le R  \\
M_1-M_2(|x|-R)   & R<|x|\le R+\frac{M_1}{M_2}  \\
0    & |x|>R+\frac{M_1}{M_2}
\end{cases}
$$
and  choose suitable $R>0$ such that
$$
\int_{R^n} |x|g(x) dx= M_3 
$$
then, how to show for any $f$ such that
$$
f\le M_1
,~~~
|\nabla f|\le M_2
,~~~
\int_{R^n} |x|f(x) dx \le  M_3 
$$
there is
$$
\int_{R^n}  f(x) dx \le \int_{R^n} g(x)dx
$$

PS: This is a guess of me. I feel it is right. But I fail to prove it. Therefore, I ask here. Thanks for any help.